# Beamer and isomath

Tags: fonts, beamer, isomath

I would like to use the package `isomath` (to force slanted capital Greek letters in mathmode) in `beamer` slides.

Beamer replaces the standard mathmode font with a sans-serif one. However, when using `isomath` with it, the slanted capital Greek letters appear with the same Serif font used in normal TeX documents. How can I obtain slanted sans-serif capital Greek letters that match the rest of the mathmode font used in Beamer?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{isomath}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
I like $\Pi$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

The \Pi here is rendered using a serif font that does not match the rest of the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `OMLmaths*` option.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[OMLmaths*]{isomath}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
I like $\mathsf{\Pi}$ and $\mathit{\Pi}$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works, but conflicts with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. I disabled it anyway.

Comment: I get error: `Package keyval Error: OMLmaths* undefined.`  Any idea?

Comment: Why does this only appear to work for Π? I tried with `\mu` and `\mathsf{\mu}` and just got the standard mathematical serif µ.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation of `isomath` tells you that there are not many sans serif math fonts available:

> cmbright
>   arev
>   iwona
>   hvmath
>   lxfonts

With

```
\usepackage{arev,arevmath}
\usepackage{isomath}
```

I get a slanted Pi.

You can also try `\usepackage{cmbright}`.

Comment: But this would have the side effect of changing the math font for the rest of the document, wouldn't it?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Yes. I don't find the Arev fonts so bad.

Comment: Is it possible to use `cmbright` for math only?  I find `arevmath` too heavy, plus `\Phi` is ugly.

Comment: @Pygmalion I think you can